# Stash Error: "unknown cache type"

Tags: stash

I'm using Stash `append_list` and `get_list` tags to output a set of entries grouped by channel. Below it I have a separate channel entries loop with a simple date checker plugin:

```
{exp:channel:entries
  channel='cookies|cakes|pies'
  dynamic='no'
  cat_id='375'
  disable='member_data|pagination|category_fields'
  sort='asc'
  status='not closed'
  parse='inward'
}
  {exp:stash:append_list name='treats' context='{channel_short_name}'}
    {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
  {/exp:stash:append_list}
{/exp:channel:entries}

<h3>Study Materials</h3>
<ul class="study-materials">
  {exp:stash:get_list name='treats' context='cookies' process='end' parse_tags='yes' parse_conditionals='yes'}
    {title}<br>
  {/exp:stash:get_list}

  {exp:stash:get_list name='treats' context='cakes' process='end' parse_tags='yes' parse_conditionals='yes'}
    {title}<br>
  {/exp:stash:get_list}

  {exp:stash:get_list name='treats' context='pies' process='end' parse_tags='yes' parse_conditionals='yes'}
    {title}<br>
  {/exp:stash:get_list}
</ul>

{exp:channel:entries
  channel='purchased_items'
  limit='1'
  dynamic='no'
  disable='pagination|categories'
  search:purchased_id='{subscription_ids}'
  author_id='{logged_in_member_id}'
} 
  {exp:entry_age type='older' days_old='365' entry_date='{entry_date}'}
    <p>Your plan has expired. <a href="{path='features-and-pricing'}">Renew.</a></p>
  {/exp:entry_age}

  {if no_results}
    <p>You are on the free plan. <a href="{path='features-and-pricing'}">Purchase a subscription</a></p>
  {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I get this error when I access the template:

> Stash: unknown cache type defined by the type="" parameter.older

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a Stash bug. Fixed in v2.4.3. [More Info.](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/stash/viewthread/10871)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions.

1) You have a problem with parse order. The get_list is parsed before append_list. Try wrapping the channel entries tag in a set_list instead. Refer to stash docs and examples.

2) change the get_lists to this

```
{exp:stash:get_list name='treats' context='pies'}
    {title}<br>
  {/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Removed these:

- parse_tags='yes' - you dont have any tags inside the get_list
- parse_conditionals='yes' - you dont have any conditionals inside the
  get_list
- process='end' - this may be further confusing the parse    order

Then remove the second channel entries tag and get the top part of template working first.